# why user not send email from site in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, community

In salesforce when i send email from visualforce page email sent but on site email not sending.

```
 List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();
    toaddresses.add('sumit@kcloudtechnologies.com');
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    message.toAddresses = toAddresses;
    message.subject = 'Immediate and Urgent New Customer';
    message.plainTextBody = 'We see that you have recently been in touch with us. We will notify our sales team and they will contact you within the next 4 hours.';

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};

    try{
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
        for(Messaging.SendEmailResult rr:results){
            System.debug('Email result ' + rr.IsSuccess());
            Error_Log__c er = new Error_Log__c();
            er.Error_Description__c = String.valueof(rr.IsSuccess());//'Error "'+e.getMessage()+'" occured at line number '+e.getLineNumber();
            er.Error_Date_Time__c = System.now();
            er.Error_Source__c = 'Failed Payment Automation Batch';
            //er.Log_Data__c = scope+'';
            insert er;
        } 
   }
     catch(DmlException e) {
        Error_Log__c er = new Error_Log__c();
        er.Error_Description__c = 'Error "'+e.getMessage()+'" occured at line number '+e.getLineNumber();
        er.Error_Date_Time__c = System.now();
        er.Error_Source__c = 'Failed Payment Automation Batch';
        //er.Log_Data__c = scope+'';
        insert er;

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by when I send email from visualforce page email sent but on site email not sending.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the email of the guest user in the site and it works
[image]